# Optimistic locking on writes in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, locking, nonblocking

I've noticed when I do the following:

```
update t set x = 1 where x = 0; // (1) session 1
update t set x = 2 where x = 0; // (2) session 2
commit; // (3) session 2
```

At line (2), session 2 will wait for session (1) to commit.

The issue is that I may have lots of users using this table, but I don't want one holding the session open to block all other users.

Ideally, I'd like the session 2 commit to succeed, and then session 1 to throw an error when it attempts to commit, as described here: [Optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control#OCC_phases).

Is there a way to get Oracle to behave in this way? (I'm using Oracle 10g if that makes a difference).

**Rationale and (perhaps bad) solution**

I have a nightly replication process that can affect rows on the table. I don't want this to be blocked by a user who leaves open a session on one of those rows.

The only way I can think of to work around this to not give users direct table access, but instead create an updatable view or PL/SQL functions that write to a temporary table, and then provide the user a procedure that performs the actual writes and commits. This way, the time that rows will be locked will be only during the execution of the "commit procedure", which would be limited.

I'd like a solution that is something like this but preferably easier.

Comment: Just curious why your lots of users update lots of same rows in the table?

Comment: I'd look at fixing the actual problem ( users leaving sessions open with uncommited data ) rather than trying to work around it with a hacky solution. Perhaps look into using resource manager to kill off sessions from certain users who have had a long running update.